# validate work only for first element

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I go to dynamically created same elements after the page is loaded ,but validate work only for first element.

```
        $('[name="DirectionSide"]').each(function (indx, element) {

        $([action="/Data/CreateAdvertisingDesign"]').validate();
        $(element).rules('add', {
            required: true
        });
        }
    );
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Enlight us with some details please..:)

Comment: has your for each got more then 1 link to it?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your OP.  Missing the opening quote in the second jQuery selector.  Are you using `unobtrusive-validation` plugin as part of ASP?  If so, you cannot call the `.validate()` method on your form since the unobtrusive plugin has already automatically done this for you.  You also cannot call it more than one time.

Answer (score 2):

If you create your fields dynamically you should parse `form` again to allow `jquery.validate` find new elements. You can do it with this lines:

```
$('#your-form').data('validator', null); 
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#your-form');
```